# Autowiring of @Repository interface fails in concrete class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a concrete class implementing an interface as below:

```
@Service
public class BaseImpl implements Base{
  @Autowired
  Details details;
  ...
  public void doSomething(){
  }
}
```

Code for the interface:

```
@Service
public interface Base{
  void doSomething();
}
```

My configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean(name="samplebean")
    public Base getImpl(){
        return new BaseImpl();
    }
}
```

And the Details interface (which is annotated with @Repository):

```
@Repository
public interface Details extends CrudRepository<..., ...>{
    ...
}
```

Finally, I call the BaseImpl class as below:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "...")
public class Caller{
  public void foo(){
    Base b = (Base) context.getBean("samplebean");
    b.doSomething();
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.model.Details com.pkg.BaseImpl.details; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.model.Details] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.model.Details] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 37 more
```

However, when I do the same auto-wiring in the Caller class (or for that matter any other class which is not implementing an interface), it seems to work fine. I'm new to Spring, so I might be missing something here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell spring about the Details bean. Either declare it as a bean,

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean(name="samplebean")
    public Base getImpl(){
        return new BaseImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public Details details() {
        return new Details();
    }
}
```

or annotate it with `@Component` (or some other more appropriate stereotype)

```
@Component
public class Details {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The Details interface is annotated with @Repository. I'm sorry I forgot to add the code for that. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are annotating your `Details` class with `@Repository`, you just need to add `@ComponentScan` annotation to your configuration class with the correct base package names.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "<yourBasePackage>" })
```

Comment: I haven't created any instance of "Details" in my configuration class.

Comment: @drunkenfist - Updated my answer to remove unnecessary information.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm using Spring boot. Do I need to add [@]ComponentScan again? Wouldn't  [@]SpringBootApplication do that? Besides, if I autowire Details in another class which is not an implementation class, then it works fine. It's only when I try to autowire it in an implementing class that I get the error.

Comment: Yes, you have to add `@ComponentScan` in the `AppConfig` class, because spring boot only scans for your configuration classes which in turn need to scan your application specific beans/repository/component.

Comment: @Mithun Adding ComponentScan in the AppConfig class breaks everything. Spring is not able to autowire any of the objects. I added the ComponentScan in my Caller class, but I'm still getting the error. For now, I'm Autowiring my Repository class in Caller and then passing it to the BaseImpl class. I have been looking for a solution online, but have never seen an example of Autowiring in a concrete class which implements an interface.

Comment: Moreover, the autowiring works properly if I remove the "implements Base" from BaseImpl class. It fails only when the class implements interface.

Comment: Could you please add the sample project to github and share the link? This will help in resolving the issue faster.